# How to Extended Table Class CakePhp3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

I need extends ModelTable class to add follow method just one time, and not in each class

```
public function addOrUpdate($data, $options=[])   {
  if ($this->existe($data)) {
    $obj = $this->findById($data['id'])->first();
    $obj = $this->patchEntity($obj, $data,$options);
  }else{
  $obj = $this->newEntity($data,$options);
  }
  return $this->save($obj);
 }
```

Comment: Your question is kinda unclear, as it doesn't seem to describe the actual technical problem that you're facing, please add more information and describe the full picture, so that people that cannot look over your shoulder, are able to reenact the problem - thanks!

Comment: I only need extends a Table Class in cakePhp..  code not matter but a example

Comment: CakePHP is PHP, classes can be extended like any other class in PHP. But that's probably not what you want to hear, so again, please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an CustomTable class extending Table class. Place your function inside CustomTable class.Then you can create each model table class extending CustomTable class.

```
class CustomTable extends Table {

    public function addOrUpdate($data, $options = [])
    {
        ...
    }
}

class ModelTable extends CustomTable {
    ...
}
```